# Update employees table

Tags: sql, oracle

Guys I have the following problem:

Increase salary 15% for employees whose salary is less than 50% of their manager's salary.
Write PL/SQL procedure using cursor, loop and update.

Procedure header
Create or replace procedure `inc_salary` is:

. Exception if their salary after increase is more than 50% of their manager's salary.

Actually, we can do it directly like this:

```
update emp e
set e.salary+=e.salary*0.15
where e.salary<(select e.mgr from emp e, group by e.mgr)
```

Here is a picture of this table:
    [image]

But I don't understand how to use the procedure. If I declare it like this, create or replace procedure `inc_salary`, then what should be its parameters? We can use of course loop, like

```
declare
for r in (select * from emp e) loop
update  emp e
set r.salary+=r.salary*0.15;
where r.salary<r.mgr
exception
if r.salary >r.mgr*1.15  then
dbms.output_putline(' it can't increase');
end loop;
end;
```

But how to combine it together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need a PL/SQL procedure? A simple query would do this job!

```
UPDATE emp
SET salary = salary * 1.15
WHERE empno IN (
    SELECT e.empno
      FROM emp e
      JOIN emp m ON e.mgr = m.empno
     WHERE e.salary < m.salary * 0.5
)
```

That's it!

But, if at all you need to use a procedure, you have to decide for yourself what exactly you want to do with it.

Every procedure has a set of formal parameters, which can even be an empty set. It is you who decides what to pass to a procedure. Consult your manager or architect for these situations.

Comment: by the way how can i connect  e.mgr to e.empno?

Comment: It is `m.empno` if you look closely.

Comment: it does not  matter,what to pass,just  how can i use it,feel free to pass anything in procedure

Comment: I would suggest read Oracle documentation on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_packages.htm

Comment: But before you read it, I would like you to rethink what you need. If you just want to update salaries in one table, the `UPDATE` query is enough. If you want to run this update query for any table you want then I would suggest you build a procedure with a dynamic SQL statement that would execute as per the parameters you provide to the procedure. It is only you who decides what you need to do. People can only help with how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
prec number;
 procedure inc_salary(prcin number) 
is
cursor cl is * from employees;
msal number(8,2);
mid number(6);
begin
for r in cl loop
  mid := nvl(r.manager_id, r.employee_id);
  select salary into msal from employees where employee_id = mid;
  if r.salary < (msal * 0.5) then
     update employees set
     salary = salary * prc
     where employee_id = r.employee_id;
     end if;
   end loop;
end inc_salary;
 begin 
 prec := 1.5;
inc_salary(prec);
end ;
```